# Cópia de array em ADVPL

Tags: array, advpl

Em ADVPL qual a diferença de fazer:

```
aArray1 := {"A", "B", "C"}

aArray2 := aArray1
```

ou

```
aArray2 := aClone(aArray1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A primeira atribuição faz apenas referencia a memória, fazendo os dois arrays apontarem para mesma posição de memória. Então temos:

```
Conout(aArray1[2]) //Imprime B
aArray2[2] := "R" //Altera o segundo array faz a alteração no primeiro
Conout('aArray1[2]) //Imprime R
```

No caso caso 2 o array é copiado:

```
aArray2 := aClone(aArray1)
Conout(aArray1[2]) //Imprime B
aArray2[2] := "R" //Altera o segundo array não faz a alteração no primeiro
Conout('aArray1[2]) //Imprime B
```

Obs.
Sempre que utilizamos um array, em especial quando clonamos eles com aClone, deve-se ao final do uso limpar o espaço utilizado na memória com a função aSize.

```
aArray2 := aSize(array2,0) //Zera o uso da memoria.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao fazer uma atribuição simples de um array usando o operador ':=' uma variável fará referência ao endereço de memória da outra, utilizando a função aClone() (http://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/AClone) será atribuída a variável uma cópia real do array.

Answer (score 0):

Resumindo: O primeiro aponta para o array um por referencia apenas, o segundo gera uma copia completa e independente dele.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).